# Is it possible to export layers scale-based visibility to a webmap?

Tags: qgis, web-mapping

Is it possible to make or convert a QGIS map into an interactive webpage map? For example, I have layers that appear at certain zoom levels, is there a way to have that interaction on the map for HTML/Webpage?

Comment: Have you tried it? Using qgis2leaf?

Comment: No, I was just wondering if it was even possible first, and if it is how to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible for OpenLayers 3 export, using qgis2web. However, scale-dependent visibility is not yet supported for Leaflet output.

Comment: I just released qgis2web 0.16.0, which supports scale-dependent visibility in Leaflet output.

Answer (score 2):

Most web mapping programs make this pretty easy to achieve. In [MangoMap](https://mangomap.com) for example you can just set the minimum and maximum scale for each layer:

[image]

To take this one further you can even stack the same layer on top of itself and change the symbology based on the scale, this is useful if you want to add more detail as the map is zoomed in.

Comment: I was hoping to do it using QGIS, sice there is a way with QGIS2LEAF, I just dont know how to fully use QGIS2LEAD